# Unable to login in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to login using external authentication in mvc application, but I am not able to do that.

I have changed the table name from AspNetUserLogins to LMS_UserLogins and updated also in context class but still it is giving me error as follows

> Invalid object name 'AspNetUserLogins'.

Below is my context class

```
public class LMSContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    private readonly string _strConnectionString;
    private readonly AppTenant tenant;


    public LMSContext(AppTenant tenant)
    {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }
    public LMSContext(String ConnectionString)
    {
        _strConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(tenant.ConnectionString);

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("LMS_User").HasKey(p => new { p.Id });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("LMS_Roles").HasKey(p => new { p.Id });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>().ToTable("LMS_UserClaims").HasKey(p => new { p.Id });

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("LMS_UserLogins").HasKey(p => new { p.ProviderKey, p.LoginProvider});

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().ToTable("LMS_UserRoles").HasKey(p => new { p.RoleId, p.UserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>().ToTable("LMS_RoleClaims").HasKey(p => new { p.Id });


    }

}
```

And After successful authentication on LinkedIn site, I am trying to login into application using provider name and key received as follows

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.

        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(5, "User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return View("Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
            var email = info.ExternalPrincipal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = email });
        }
    }
```

Here it is giving me error while signing as Invalid object name 'AspNetUserLogins' though I have mapped the table name in context class.

I am using VS2015, Entity Framework - 7 and Identity Framework - 3.

Why this is so ? What changes I need to do ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: have you checked basic things like the names of the tables in the SQL database? Did you run the migration after changing the names in the code? etc etc

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama Yes I have checked everything,table name is correct and also migration scripts ran successfully.

Comment: and that table does not exist in your db? assuming you are debugging/running through VS, have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama Yes it does exists and restarted VS for 2 times. I have observed the method `await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` which internally uses `UserLoginInfo` class. Is that causing issue ?

Comment: well I'm not quite sure, I can't debug for you ;) I would recommend that you check your dbcontexts and make sure there is no reference to that table anywhere in your code, implied or otherwise. There are many resources online on how to use identity with changed table names, etc. have a look at those to see what you might have missed

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama I am using default login logic method and not the customized method